# what is different between paintcomponent() and paintcomponents()?

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I want to know what is different between paintcomponent() and paintcomponents()?

when i use from paintcomponent it shows every thing that we want,but paintcomponents didn't do any thing!

Comment: I think `paintComponent` paints the current component (i.e. the one with the `paintComponent` method being called) and `paintComponents` paints the components of the current component. I may be mistaken in this, which is why it's a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick browser of the source of [`java.awt.Container.paintComponents`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Container.java#Container.paintComponents%28java.awt.Graphics%29) it seems like it (indirectly) calls paint (after some other processing) on it's child components, and the only reason you'd override it is if you want to do something funky with it.  Generally unless you really know what you're doing you probably shouldn't override it and instead should just override `paintComponent` on the appropriate control.